# Twitter SDK IOS : Compose using native Twitter App?

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, sdk

I've integrated Fabric Framework in my project, now i want to compose my image by using Twitter App installed from App Store, but twitter use `SLComposeViewController` UI of iOS, so i don't know what is different between using `SLComposeViewController` and Twitter SDK ?.
When i use Facebook SDK, sharing will use facebook app, with Twitter it not.

## I use this code to compose Image.

```
TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];

[composer setText:@"just setting up my Fabric"];
[composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fabric"]];

[composer showWithCompletion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
    if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");
    }
}];
```

Comment: could you please be more specific? is this a conceptual answer or about code?